# how do I check if a 'Review' has already been written by a given @current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For  my model Vendor:

```
:has_many Review
```

And Each User:

```
:has_many Review
```

And Each Review:

```
:belongs_to Vendor
:belongs_to User
```

So.  I don't one a User to be able to write more than one Review, so I want to do a check on the vendors/:vendorId URL which is the "show" action, and have a way to make the "Write Review" button disappear or appear based on whether for the @current_user there has already been written a Review for that specific Vendor.

I know the @vendor.id and @loggedin_user.id but not sure how to do a find on two parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  If you just want to find on two parameters, you can do:

```
Review.find(:first, :conditions => {:user_id => @user.id, :vendor_id => @vendor.id})
```

You can also make use of the associations, like the following:

```
@current_user.reviews.find(:first, :conditions => {:vendor => @vendor})
```

A named_scope would be another way:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :for_vendor, lambda {|vendor| 
    {:conditions => {:vendor => vendor}}
  }
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :user
end

@current_user.reviews.for_vendor(@vendor).empty?
```

Since it's a business rule, I'd recommend encapsulating this logic in a method on either User or Vendor, like:

```
def can_review?(vendor)
  self.reviews.find(:first, :conditions => {:vendor => @vendor}).nil?
end
```

You could then do, in the view:

```
<%= review_vendor_button if @current_user.can_review?(@vendor) %>
```